# Ошибка слияния манифеста

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

После добавления в gradle:

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

Выскакивает такая Ошибка:

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-25:19 to override.

Мой gradle файл:

dependencies {

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'


implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

Подскажите плиз, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: `Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-25:19 to override.`

Comment: Не работает( Пишет другую ошибку

Comment: Cкорее всего проблема в том, что в зависимостях указаны новые библиотеки (androidx), лейауты написаны по старинке - попробуйте мигрировать проект на androidx. В андроид студии Refactor -- Migrate to AndroidX